# Get 2 divs 1 below other while third fills up the space

Tags: html, css

Is it possible (without using floats) to achieve having 2 divs one below the other, while the third one fills up the space.  However, the following HTML cannot be changed; and also we can't use cannot use floats.

Here is what I tried:

```css
div{
  width: 33%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
}

.left{
  background: blue;
}

.right{
  background: green;
}

.middle{
  width: 50%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

As you can see, the 2 divs on the left are pushed down. Is there a way to make them move up or another way to achieve this altogether?

JS Fiddle for anyone who wants it: https://jsfiddle.net/g6j7nLp5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you can't do this without adding an extra container.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="wrapper">
        <div class="item">Hello</div>
        <div class="item">hello2</div>
        <div class="item">hello3</div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.wrapper {
      display: -webkit-box;
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
      -webkit-box-direction: normal;
          -ms-flex-flow: column wrap;
              flex-flow: column wrap;
      height: 500px;
      max-width: 500px;
    }

    .item {
      background: lightblue;
      width: 50%;
      height: 50%;
    }
    .item:last-child {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-color: green;
    }
```

Check it out on [codepen](https://codepen.io/diego-fortes/pen/KNJoQx). Good luck!

Comment: I tried adding height to first element, and it broke it. Here is codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMrdvK

Comment: You never mentioned you needed specific height for each item... what exactly do you want to do? We are all working in the dark here trying to achieve something very unclear, sir. :\

Comment: The height is actually dynamic, I don't know what it will be. I brought that up as I was testing various scenarios. Was really wondering if this is expected behavior. I think your solution will work for my specific scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/):

```css
body {
 display:grid;
 grid-template-areas: 
    "left mid"
    "right mid";
 grid-gap:10px;
}

.left{
  background: blue;
  grid-area:left;
}

.right{
  background: green;
  grid-area:right;
}

.middle{
  height: 200px;
  grid-area:mid;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="middle"></div>
<div class="right"></div>
```

Comment: Your solution almost works for me. The problem I have is that the height of the left 2 divs depends on the right div. It seems both left divs are 50% of the right div. Now if my content on top left div doesn't fill out, than it creates a huge gap between two divs on the left. Is there a way to control the height of the left div without specifying i t? For example think of left side as menus that you can expand and contract in height. So you will never know what the height is. I'd like the left 2 divs be the height of the text without specifying the height. https://jsfiddle.net/0yxwbv1x/2/

Comment: @Bojan exaclty :) like in your code where both are half the right one that's why i made them like that ... but for your new requirement i don't think grid system will be a good solution for you you may needto at least add another container

Answer (score -1):

You want to use **flex** if you can wrap your three DIVs with a wrapper.

[See a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g6j7nLp5/10/)

It can't be done without a container (perhaps the `<body>`) unless you use `absolute` positioning or `float`s.  Both those might be possible for you (we don't have many details) but they would be problematic.

```
div{
  height: 100px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%; // need for compat
}

.left{
  background: blue;
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}

.right{
  background: green;
  flex: 0 0 20px;
}

.middle{
  background: red;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: **to achieve having 2 divs one below the other, while the third one fills up the space**